# React Redux, Uncaught TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function, when trying to dispatch a form submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm not sure what is causing the problem, as I have another component that's almost identical except that the other component is stateless. I'm not sure if that makes a problem? It shouldn't right?

The following code gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function at Signup.handleRegister`, when trying to submit the form.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { registerUser } from '../../actions/index';

export class Signup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            displayname: "",
            username: "",
            password: ""
        }
    }

    handleRegister = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('triggered handle register'); //logs: 'triggered handle register'
        console.log(this.state);                  //logs: {displayname: "", username: "", password: ""}, as intended with empty inputs
        console.log(this.props);                  //logs: {}
        this.props.dispatch(registerUser(this.state));
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="form-container sign-up-container">
                <form className="sign-up-form" onSubmit={this.handleRegister}>
                    <h2>Create Account</h2>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Display Name" onChange={e => this.setState({ displayname: e.target.value })} />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })} />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })} />
                    <button className="toggle-btn">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Signup);
```

Update: Something like this?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        //the redux-action here instead of the handleRegister?
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Signup);
```

Update 2: Following Christopher Ngo suggestion

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { registerUser } from '../../actions/index';

export class Signup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            displayname: "",
            username: "",
            password: ""
        }
    }

    handleRegister = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('triggered handle register'); //logs: 'triggered handle register'
        console.log(this.state);                  //logs: {displayname: "", username: "", password: ""}, as intended with empty inputs
        console.log(this);                  
//logs: Signup {props: {…}, context{…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, handleRegister: ƒ, …}
        this.props.registerUser(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-container sign-up-container">
                <form className="sign-up-form" onSubmit={this.handleRegister}>
                    <h2>Create Account</h2>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Display Name" onChange={e => this.setState({ displayname: e.target.value })} />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })} />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })} />
                    <button className="toggle-btn">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        registerUser: (userInfo) => {
            dispatch(registerUser(userInfo))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Signup);
```

I changed the console log in the handle register to check `this` and it looks like the Signup component still does not have props or dispatch available to it.

Comment: As we have to pass mapDispatchToProps function to the connect method as a second argument, you have to pass that for dispatching any action from the component.

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal Can you provide an example what that might look like in my update?

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal Also from the docs, `The default mapDispatchToProps is simply dispatch => ({ dispatch }). If you do not provide mapDispatchToProps, dispatch will be provided as mentioned above.` So why would I need to put mapDispatchToProps in the connect method?

Comment: @Kaleidics. I just provided you an example on how to implement this, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Kaleidics Are you importing Signup Component as `import {Signup} from '/path/to/Signup'`

Comment: @ Shubham Khatri Yes... that fixed it. This is actually the second time I forgot to take off the curly braces after rewriting a component to use connect. :(

Comment: @Kaleidics Glad it helped. I added it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connected component is exported as a default export so you need to make sure that you are importing `Signup` as a default import in your other files and not a named export. In such scenarios its better to not export unconnected components to avoid such mistakes.

Import your signup component like

```
import Signup from 'path/to/Signup'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { registerUser } from '../../actions/index';

class Signup extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        displayname: "",
        username: "",
        password: ""
    }
}

handleRegister = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('triggered handle register'); //logs: 'triggered handle register'
    console.log(this.state);                  //logs: {displayname: "", username: "", password: ""}, as intended with empty inputs
    console.log(this.props);                  //logs: {}
    this.props.registerUser(this.state);
}

render(){
    return (
        <div className="form-container sign-up-container">
            <form className="sign-up-form" onSubmit={this.handleRegister}>
                <h2>Create Account</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Display Name" onChange={e => this.setState({ displayname: e.target.value })} />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })} />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })} />
                <button className="toggle-btn">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
      registerUser: (userInfo) => {
         dispatch(registerUser(userInfo))
      }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Signup);
```

Comment: I changed the connect method to `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Signup);` since the console was complaining about syntax. With that, I am still getting `this.props.registerUser is not a function`

Comment: @Kaleidics Can you update your original post with your updated code? There might be something we're missing.

Comment: @Kaleidics I think their could be a problem with having two sets of exports, try getting rid of the one on top.

Comment: Thanks for the help Christopher Ngo, but I just figured it out... I was importing it with the curly braces after having changed the default export to the connect.

Comment: @Kaleidics Oh lol. Now thats a twist. Well I hope you learned something about mapDispatchToProps at the very least :)